# Can you capture a popup and load it in the parent/opener screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an app where I have a flash app that access a URL through an iFrame. The contents of the iFrame is 3rd party content. The content is a menu that you can navigate through but once you get to a certain point, the menu launches a pop up, and the popup is the continuation of the menu.

I was wondering if there is anyway that I could capture the popup and make it load within the parent/opener page, using jQuery perhaps to change the contents of the iframe?

This solution is probably way out there but I was just hoping for a nice quick fix.

The reason that this is a problem is that the app is for a tablet and the popup doesn't appear within an app on the tablet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iFrame content is served from a different domain than the parent/owner document, you're out of luck - that is, if you have no control over the iframe content. This is due to [JavaScript's same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

If you *are* able to modify the web app running inside the iframe, you could try using [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) (HTML5) to notify the parent window.